# On dragging one jqueryUI draggable element trigger drag on other multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have for example three draggable elements like follows:

```
<div class="draggable main">Main</div>
<div class="draggable followers">Follower</div>
<div class="draggable followers">Follower2</div>
```

If `.main` is dragged, We need `.followers` to be dragged too. Not just positions but also triggering all the draggable events in them like start, drag, stop. Note, the followers will be normal draggable elements. Just when .main is dragged they should be moving with it as if they are in the same draggable element triggering all the `.follower` draggable elements' events too.

Here is the JS

```
jQuery('.draggable.followers').draggable();
jQuery('.draggable.main').draggable({
    // If .main is dragged, We need .followers to be dragged too. Not just positions but also triggering all the draggable events in them like start, drag, stop.
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/9x56E/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just "cheat" a little by shuffling the HTML around a little like this:

```
<div class="special-draggable">
    <div class="main">Main</div>
    <div class="draggable followers">Follower</div>
    <div class="draggable followers">Follower2</div>
</div>
```

Adjust the CSS a little:

```
.draggable{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}
.main{
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 60px;
}
```

And then the jQuery:

```
jQuery('.draggable.followers').draggable();
jQuery('.special-draggable').draggable();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/9x56E/2/

**EDIT**: Sorry, missed the part about it having to trigger the draggable events...

How about this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.draggable.followers').draggable();
    $('.draggable.main').draggable();

    /* trigger dragstart on followers when main is dragged */
    $('.draggable.main').on('dragstart', function() {
        $('.draggable.followers').each(function() {
            $(this).trigger('dragstart');
        });
    });

    /* trigger drag on followers when main is dragged and adjust position */
    $('.draggable.main').on('drag', function() {
        var maintop = $(this).css('top');
        var mainleft = $(this).css('left');

        $('.draggable.followers').each(function() {
            $(this).trigger('drag');
            $(this).addClass('ui-draggable-dragging');
            $(this).css('margin-left', mainleft);
        });

        $('.draggable.followers:first').css('margin-top', maintop);
    });

    /* trigger dragstop on followers when main is dragged and adjust position */
    $('.draggable.main').on('dragstop', function() {
        var maintop = $(this).css('top');
        var mainleft = $(this).css('left');

        $('.draggable.followers').each(function() {
            $(this).trigger('dragstop');
            $(this).removeClass('ui-draggable-dragging');
            $(this).css('margin-left', mainleft);
        });

       $('.draggable.followers:first').css('margin-top', maintop);
    });


    /* test different actions on .followers */
    $('.draggable.followers').on('dragstart', function() {
        // do something
    });

    $('.draggable.followers').on('drag', function() {
        // do something
    });

    $('.draggable.followers').on('dragstop', function() {
        // do something
    });

});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/6TZp3/

Comment: There is a problem with this cheat. As I said the .followers need to trigger their stop, drag and start events side by side with the .main element.
And unfortunately I cant have these elements grouped in the common wrapper.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part of the question first... I've added a different solution above.

Comment: Thanks Niffler, found out that the trigger would only work for the event handler attached using the on() and not the callback defined in the object during the initialization of the draggable itself.